# mysql-connector-python error 1045 (28000): Access denied for user using password: YES

Tags: mysql-error-1045

I am having trouble connecting to a mysql / mariadb database. I am getting the following error in jupyter lab:

```
ProgrammingError: 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'xx'@'yy' (using password: YES)
```

Here is my code:

```
    import mysql.connector as mariadb

    CONFIG_READ ={'user': 'xx', 'password': 'zz', 
'host': 'myadress', 'database': 'dbname', 'raise_on_warnings': True}  
#i'm sure the entered info here is correct
        
        def read(query, params=()):
            try:
                conn = mariadb.connect(**CONFIG_READ)
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                cursor.execute(query, params)
                result = cursor.fetchall()
            finally:
                conn.close()
            return result
```

I am running this in a docker container where mysql-connector-python 8.0.27 is installed. I would really like to hear your advise on how to solve this problem. On stack I could only find solutions by manually adjusting mysql settings in pip, that didn't help in my case, since we need this specific version of mysql-connector-python to connect to another db. Is there a way to fix this from linux bash?

Looking forward to hear from you.

Greetings,
Jerome

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem with `mysql.connector`. Use the `pymysql` module, it connects the same way. Just read the documentation because method argument names might not be the same!

Comment: I tried your method, used pymysql and I get a similar error message as a result:  OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'xxx@'yyy' (using password: YES)")

Comment: I'm sorry to answer you this late. To connect to the database use this line of code: `db = pymysql.connect(host='{your_database_ip}', database='{your_database_name}', user='{your_username}', password='{your_password}')`. Btw check if you can connect to MariaDB using MySQL modules.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up! I was able to solve this problem by removing the old user and creating a new one via the root account. Then I applied: GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON asterisk.asterisk TO 'newusername'@'%'; and subsequently GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON asterisk.asterisk TO 'newusername'@'::1' and lastly GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON asterisk.asterisk TO 'username'@'ipadres'. Only that seemed to fix the problem... Here, asterisk = *